# Count number of orderlines using multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join, count

I'm currently working on a query to see how many orders we have with a specific item. this item can have multiple product codes.
We also want to know how many orderlines there are in total per order that falls in this query.

We now have:

```
SELECT 
    O06T1.deldate, O06T1.ordno,O06T1.ordstat,O06T1.r00key,
    O04T90.avemail,O04T90.avphone,
    COUNT( O08T1.ordno) AS Orderlines
FROM O06T1 
JOIN O08T1 ON O08T1.shorto04 = O06T1.shorto04
JOIN O04T90 ON O04T90.shorto04 = O06T1.shorto04
WHERE
    (NOT O06T1.ordstat IN (0,9,25) )
    AND (NOT O06T1.ordtype = 11)
    AND (
        O08T1.partno IN (
            '071689000',
            '080227000',
            '079857000',
            '079858000',
            '079859000',
            '079860000'
            )
    )
GROUP BY
    O06T1.deldate, O06T1.ordno,O06T1.ordstat,
    O06T1.r00key,O04T90.avemail,O04T90.avphone
ORDER BY
    O06T1.ordno DESC;
```

---

O06T1 is the table with the orders.
O08T1 is the table with all the orderlines.

The problem i now have is that I only get a few orders that all have 1 orderlines according to this query. But when I look them up they have more (20-40) what is happening?

Comment: That's expected behaviour, your 'count' is 'count of lines with the same  O06T1.deldate, O06T1.ordno,O06T1.ordstat,    O06T1.r00key,O04T90.avemail, O04T90.avphone' where PartNO is in the list of part numbers...  You probably only have one row with each combination.

Comment: what is  this column for "shorto04" i think this the source of your problem "JOIN O08T1 ON O08T1.shorto04 = O06T1.shorto04"

Comment: the collumn shorto04 is a collumn used in different tables. in the O04T90 are the e-mail adresses where the shorto04 is the unique key value, and the only column used in every table